# Replace keys based on another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects, Based on one array I need to replace the key of another array. Tried to use Object.Keys() but could not achieve it. Kindly suggest

```js
// **Input :**
let sim = {
  "header": [{
      "VKORG": "1000",
      "VTWEG": "10"
    },
    {
      "VKORG": "1000",
      "VTWEG": "20"
    }
  ]
}
// **Reference Array:**
let columns = [{
      "FIELD": "VKORG",
      "FIELD_DESC": "Sales Organization"
    },
    {
      "FIELD": "VTWEG",
      "FIELD_DESC": "Distribution Channel"
    }
  ]

/// **Code I tried** 


for (let i = 0; i < sim.header.length; i++) {

  if (Object.keys(sim[i].header) === Object.keys(columns[i].header)) {
    sim[i].header[columns[i].header.FIELD_DESC] = sim[i].header[Object.keys(sim[i].header)]
  }
}

console.log(sim);
```

**Expected Output:**

```js
output = {
  "header": [{
      "Sales Organization": "1000",
      "Distribution Channel: "
      10 " 

    },
    {
      "Sales Organization": "1000",
      "Distribution Channel": "20"

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives console errors. Try to fix those - header does not have keys. It is an array

Comment: it should be `sim.header[i]` rather than `sim[i].header`, should also be `columns[i]["FIELD"]` as there is no property header on the elements within columns array

Comment: @Sven.hig Not neccessarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using Map and array.map . We store the columns as key value pair in Map , then while traversing the sim.header , just get the value from the map for the particular key and update it .

```js
let sim = {
  "header": [{
      "VKORG": "1000",
      "VTWEG": "10"
    },
    {
      "VKORG": "1000",
      "VTWEG": "20"
    }
  ]
}

let columns = [{
      "FIELD": "VKORG",
      "FIELD_DESC": "Sales Organization"
    },
    {
      "FIELD": "VTWEG",
      "FIELD_DESC": "Distribution Channel"
    }
]

var map = new Map();
columns.forEach(obj => {
   map.set(obj.FIELD, obj.FIELD_DESC);
})

sim.header = sim.header.map(obj => {
var tempObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
       tempObj[map.get(key)] = obj[key]
    })
    return tempObj;
})

console.log(sim);
```

Answer (score 3):

Is not perfect but try this

```js
let sim = {
    "header": [
        {
            "VKORG": "1000",
            "VTWEG": "10"

        },
        {
            "VKORG": "1000",
            "VTWEG": "20"

        }
    ]
};

let columns = [
    {
        "FIELD": "VKORG",
        "FIELD_DESC": "Sales Organization"
    },
    {
        "FIELD": "VTWEG",
        "FIELD_DESC": "Distribution Channel"
    }
];

const filter = {};
for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    filter[columns[i].FIELD] = columns[i].FIELD_DESC;
}

sim.header = sim.header.map(el => {
    const keys = Object.keys(el);
    const newObj = {}
    for (const key of keys) {
        newObj[filter[key]] = el[key];
    }
    return newObj;
});

console.log(sim);
```